# Django nvd3 Line Chart tool tip not working in case of intersection two series

Tags: django, charts, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am using Django 1.5.4, python 2.7 and django-nvd3 0.6.0, to show statistics for users.

Here is example of data I am passing to chart:

```
data = {  
'charttype': 'lineChart',  
'chartdata': {  
'x':[1388514600000L, 1388601000000L, 1388687400000L, 1388773800000L],  
'y1':[0,0,0,4],  
'y2':[1,3,2,4],  
},  
'chartcontainer': chartcontainer,  
'extra': {  
'x_is_date': True,  
'x_axis_format': '%d %b %Y %H',  
'tag_script_js': False,  
'jquery_on_ready': False,  
}  
}
```

Since y1 series and y2 series intersects at 4, it raises error Type Error: e is undefined.
And it is not showing tool tip at all.
But if you change the value of y2 to [1,3,2,5], it will work as required.

Any pointer or suggestion would be great.

Thanks,
Pradnya

Answer (score 1):

```
def demo_linechart_without_date(request):

extra_serie = {}
xdata = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
ydata = [3, 5, 7, 8, 3, 5, 3, 5, 7, 6, 3, 1]
chartdata = {
    'x': xdata,
    'name1': 'series 1', 'y1': ydata, 'extra1': extra_serie,
}
charttype = "lineChart"
chartcontainer = 'linechart_container' # container name
data = {
    'charttype': charttype,
    'chartdata': chartdata,
    'chartcontainer': chartcontainer,
    'extra': {
        'x_is_date': False,
        'x_axis_format': '',
        'tag_script_js': True,
        'jquery_on_ready': False,
    }
}
return render_to_response('linechart.html', data)
```

Comment: Thanks Pramod
But there is no issue with single series in Linechart, Issue is with multiple series in Ydata, intersecting with at some point, th chart renders but tooltip is missing.